# Google analytics fetch user id in reporting API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I like to fetch user id which is available in user explorer report google analytics.
I am using below batchGet to get the list of user ids using ga:clientId
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

I am able to get the client ids, but when trying the same id with below API 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search#request-body

Its returning 400 error not found. 
Even if I copy the user id which is visible in user explorer reporting dashboard in google analytics it still return 400 error not found.
Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Code snippet

```
analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
body={
              "viewId": VIEW_ID,
               "user": {
                 "type": "USER_ID", # I have tried CLIENT_ID Also
                 "userId": user_id # For now I have copied the value directly from the user explorer from browser itself for testing.But it didn't worked
              }
      }
 result=analytics.userActivity().search(body=body).execute()
```

Response

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ga_session_data.py", line
>   192, in 
>       ga.main()   File "ga_session_data.py", line 178, in main
>       result=analytics.userActivity().search(body=body).execute()   File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py",
>   line 130, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py",
>   line 856, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/userActivity:search?alt=json
>   returned "CLIENT_ID: XXXXXXXX not found.">

Answer (score 2):

User ID and client ID are two distinct dimensions in Google Analytics. User explorer report is based on `user ID` and this id might differ from `client Id` that appears in API report under `ga:clientId` dimension. 
To use Activity reports based on `client Id` value, use the following object in your Activity request:

```
{
  "type": "CLIENT_ID",
  "userId": "your.value"
}
```

In order to get data for particular User ID that appears User explorer report use the following object:

```
{
  "type": "USER_ID",
  "userId": "your.value"
}
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search#request-body

Comment: Yes. I had tried both of the types and value I had copied from user Explorer itself. But still it return the 400 not found.

Comment: I want to know to work with userActivity search API, from which API we should get the valid user ids

Comment: Assuming userID is provided by first-party it's supposed to be known without requesting APIs. userID is not exposed in Analytics reporting API

Comment: Okay thanks for reply.
But when I am passing the UserId which are visible in User Explorer report . For that userIDs API should have return some result right? I am confused why UserActivity API not working even I pass valid userID. Is there anything wrong with code?

Comment: could you please provide the full request and API response?

Comment: Added response in above question. For request I am using library, code for the same is already shared in question

Comment: I think this is an open issue but not sure
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130161158

Comment: could you please double-check that you're using the same date ranges in Activity request as in the user activity report?

Comment: Yes checked its the same date range

Comment: @YOGESH the API has been updated recently so I suppose it's worth trying once again:
The User Activity API is updated to correctly handle requests containing User ID specification. The User Activity API has been updated to correctly handle the case when userId field was populated with a User ID and userType field was set to USER_ID. User Activity API requests containing a User ID resulted in an error prior to the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird bug in Google Analytics' Reporting API. I stumbled upon the same problem and have figured out what is wrong here. When fetching a user recently recorded in Google Analytics, you can't simply query it with `User ID` because somehow google tries to fetch results from the previous week.

### Why Not Found?

The response from GA Reporting API is half the story, when the GA Reporting API says  `USER_ID: {xxx-yyy-zzz} not found` it never means that user is never recorded by GA, Instead what it means is that `The User you requested data for is not found in this date range`

### Solution

Make use of date while fetching users this way you are safe from  `USER_ID: {xxx-yyy-zzz} not found` error.

### Via Analytics Reporting API

`https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/userActivity:search`:

```
{
  "user": {
    "type": "USER_ID",
    "userId": "your-custom-user-id"
  },
  "viewId": "XXXXYYYY",
  "dateRange": {
    "startDate": "2022-11-12",
    "endDate": "2022-11-16"
  }
}
```

### via Hello Analytics (PHP):

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/analytics/service-account-credentials.json'));
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

    $user = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_User();
    $user->setType("USER_ID"); // pass "CLIENT_ID" for using Client ID
    $user->setUserId("your-custom-user-id"); //User ID

    $userActivityRequest = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SearchUserActivityRequest();
    $userActivityRequest->setViewId(env('ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID'));
    $userActivityRequest->setDateRange($dateRange);
    $userActivityRequest->setUser($user);

    // Passing params is optional
    $param = [
       
    ];

    $sessions = $analytics->userActivity->search($userActivityRequest, $param);
```

More info regarding this method can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)

### More Ways

- [Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)
- [Java](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java)

*Please Consider suggesting edits to improve this answer.